# Interface binding doesn't work

Tags: laravel

I bind an implementation to an interface like in the documentation. But nothing seems to work. (The interface is defined in the same file with the class Book.)

```php
// In AppServiceProvider::register()

$this->app->bind(
    'App\Item',
    'App\Book'
);

// In a controller

public function __construct(Item $x)
{
    // ReflectionException: Class App\Item does not exist
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Maybe there is a better solution...

Comment: Anyway, check if the namespace of your classes `Item` and `Book` are correct. Also check if they are inside the `app` folder of your application.

If they're really correct, go to the terminal, open your project directory and execute `composer -o -a dumpautoload; php artisan optimize`.

Comment: This command helped.

Comment: Even in development, Laravel keeps some cache of the classes. If you get stuck into `ReflectionException`s, always try this command.

Answer (score 1):

The error message that is displayed is stating that the Item class was not found.
Most of the time this error comes from errors in the namespace or class names.

Verify if you namespace is App. if you used the command `php artisan app:name`, or change namespace line in `app.config`, then your namespace is changed to name you put in that command, so you need the change every place still use App namespace. Verify if you changed namespace in that files

Item and Book are models? Make sure they are inside the `YourProjectName/app` folder. If it is not, make sure they are inside a subfolder in that directory, if they are, just change the lines `App\Item` and `App\Book` with the correct directory. Eg.:

My laravel namespace is `MyNamespace`. Inside my project folder I have `app` folder, and inside my `app` folder I have a folder called `Models` and inside that folder I have a model Book. When I will use Book model, I have to reference then with `MyNamespace\Models\Book`.

Verify if your model file is initialized whit the line `namespace YouNameSpace\ModelName;` like this, using my previus example `namespace MyNamespace\Models\Book;`